# Discrete optimisation: large number of optimal solutions

Tags: optimization, gurobi

**TL;DR version**: Is there a way to cope with optimisation problems where there exists a **large** number of **optimal** solutions (solutions that find the best objective value)? That is, finding an optimal solution is *pretty* quick (but highly dependent on the size of the problem, obviously) but many such solutions exists so that the solver runs endlessly trying to find a better solution (endlessly because it does find other feasible solutions but with an objective value equals to the current best).

**Not TL;DR version:**
For a university project, I need to implement a scheduler that should output the schedule for every university programme per year of study. I'm provided some data and for the matter of this question, will simply stick to a general but no so rare example.

In many sections, you have mandatory courses and optional courses. Sometimes, those optional courses are divided in modules and the student needs to choose one of these modules. Often, they have to select two modules, but some combinations arise more often than others. Clearly, if you count the number of courses (mandatory + optional courses) without taking into account the subdivision into modules, you happen to have more courses than time slots in which they need to be scheduled. My model is quite simple. I have constraints stating that every course should be scheduled to one and only one time slot (period of 2 hours) and that a professor should not give two courses at the same time. Those are hard constraints. The thing is, in a perfect world, I should add hard constraints stating that a student cannot have two courses at the same time. But because I don't have enough data and that every combination of modules is possible, there is no point in creating one student per combination mandatory + module 1 + module 2 and apply the hard constraints on each of these students, since it is basically identical to have one student (mandatory + all optionals) and try to fit the hard constraints - which will fail.

This is why, I decided to move those hard constraints in an optimisation problem. I simply define my objective function minimising for each student the number of courses he/she takes that are scheduled simultaneously.

If I run this simple model with only one student (22 courses) and 20 time slots, I should have an objective value of 4 (since 2 time slots embed each 2 courses). But, using Gurobi, the relaxed objective is 0 (since you can have fraction of courses inside a time slot). Therefore, when the solver does reach a solution of cost 4, it cannot prove optimality directly. The real trouble, is that for this simple case, there exists a **huge** number of **optimal** solutions (22! maybe...). Therefore, to prove optimality, it will go through all other solutions (which share the same objective) desperately trying to find a solution with a smaller gap between the relaxed objective (0) and the current one (4). Obviously, such solution doesn't exist...

Do you have any idea on how I could tackle this problem? I thought of analysing the existing database and trying to figure out which combinations of modules are very likely to happen so that I can put back the hard constraints but it seems hazardous (maybe I will select a combination that leads to a conflict therefore not finding any solution or omitting a valid combination). The current solution I use is putting a time threshold to stop the optimisation...

Comment: MIP doesn't necessarily do an exhaustive search. Sounds like you need to work on cuts and other ways to tighten the bound.

Comment: Maybe playing with Gurobi's parameters that control how aggressive cuts can be?

Comment: I would definitely think about introducing a second objective (with a low weight compared to your original objective), so that not all those solutions are optimal, but can be distinguished by some secondary value.